# Can I create a layout using the xml file and code within the activity?

Tags: android

I've just started playing around with android, so pardon me if this is a totally stupid question.

I'm trying to create a simple text based game in which I ask a question based on a movie. The list of movie's is in a text file which I've included in res/raw. So basically I want to have a default string, say "Who acted in", followed by the name of the movie. Could I have the first string (along with a submit button etc) in my res/layout/main.xml file, and follow that with the movies name, after I've extracted it from the text file in my activity, or does the layout **have** to be defined in one place only?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can mix these things. You will tell your activity to use the view based on XML.

Then you will create a TextView object(or whatever is your question made of), and use the findViewById method to get the object. Then simply call setText(newText) on it and you are done.